# Why can't I reference an object literal from inside an object literal?

Tags: javascript

not sure if this is possible or if I'm doing it wrong. I'm trying to have an object literal reference one of it's own properties that is another object literal. I keep getting an error stating that it is undefined:

```
var MyObject = {
    init: function(){
        this.elements.buttons.click(function(){
            alert('hit');
        });
    },
    elements: {
        buttons: $('button')
    }
}
```

what am i doing wrong?

UPDATE:
main.js is calling init to initialize on demand which probably doofed the scope --

```
function executeFunctionByName(functionName, context /*, args */) {
    var args = [].slice.call(arguments).splice(2);
    var namespaces = functionName.split(".");
    var func = namespaces.pop();
    for(var i = 0; i < namespaces.length; i++) {
        context = context[namespaces[i]];
    }
    return context[func].apply(this, args);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    // invoke init() for any element that requests it
    $('[data-page]').each(function(i, p){
        var page = 'APP.MODEL.' + $(p).data('page') + '.init';
        executeFunctionByName(page, window)
    });
});
```

Comment: this will refer to MyObject if you call it from there, the problem here is that click is not defined on elements, which is a regular object, not a jquery object

Comment: You should call `this.elements.buttons.click`

Comment: sorry typo. I did actually call this.elements.buttons

Comment: Updated code works actually: https://www.dropbox.com/s/krburpqrzlfq96y/Screenshot%202014-04-22%2001.05.25.png are you sure that JQuery is presented on page?

Comment: Did you try changing `this` to `MyObject`?. If it worked this way, then it has to do with the way you're calling the init function.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/s4XLa/ here is working fiddle. Your jquery is obviously not works.

Comment: @Tommi that is really weird. If I write other jquery on the page, it works fine

Comment: Maybe your code get's executed before jquery is loaded

Comment: I did think of that. Jquery is loaded in the head at the moment and the script that's not working is loaded at the bottom of the page. I'm checking all the order of executions right now.

Comment: @Sinaesthetic Could you paste the exact error that's generated in the console? It should say exactly which variable is undefined

Comment: it seems that it is elements that is undefined: http://i.imgur.com/PyNTnzP.png

Comment: How are you calling init ?

Comment: Ah. And where and how are you calling the init function? Could you add this line as the first line of the init function? `console.log(this)`

Comment: init is being called from $(document).ready() in main.js which is the last file reference

Comment: Ok there's the problem. Did you try replacing `this` temporarily with `MyObject` to see whether it works?

Comment: yeah I did in the very beginning and it works

Comment: The problem is you're calling the init function incorrectly. You probably did something like `var init = MyObject.init; init();` That would cause this problem. You would need to call `MyObject.init` directly. If that's not possible, you may use .call or .apply. I'll paste the doc for that in a sec

Comment: alright. so i called init directly from the page and it works fine so it's something to do with main.js

Comment: Ah yeah, I am doing something like that. I will post the nonsense to the OP so maybe I can salvage this

Comment: try `context[func].apply(context, args);`

Comment: @basilikum That's already being called; could you clarify?

Comment: Ok I've updated my answer with docs and showing an example of how it works. Make sure you pass `MyObject` to the call/apply function

Comment: @Sinaesthetic you call it with `this` which points to the window object, but you should call it with `context` which points to the object containing `elements`.

Comment: oh wait! you meant in executeFunctionByName. Yes that did it

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant :)

Comment: thanks guys. that was really aggravating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are invoking that function directly without going through `MyObject`, `this` would be undefined. Replace `this` with `MyObject` and it should work.

This would not work as `this` would be defined to `window`:

```
var MyObject = {
    // init: ...
}
var init = MyObject.init;
init();
```

See **3. Entering function code**: [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/javascript-this-keyword)

If you wish to continue to use `this`, you may use [Function.prototype.call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [Function.prototype.apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) like so:

```
var MyObject = {
    // init: ...
}
var init = MyObject.init;
init.call(MyObject);
```

Comment: Your answer is plain wrong, this will refer to MyObject if you call if from MyObject, the problem here is that click is not defined, this has nothing to do with it

Comment: @Willem D'haeseleer Please read what I wrote. I said WITHOUT going through MyObject

Comment: @Willem D'haeseleer Oh you're right about the click. However, the OP changed it to `buttons.click` so that's not the problem.

Comment: Very correct, but the problem still isn't related to `this`, it's probably jquery related or something. So your answer still isn't being very helpfull.

Comment: @WillemD'haeseleer Well we still don't know what the problem is so I'll leave this up here in case it helps anyone else because a lot of people actually don't know that `this` is undefined if not called from `MyObject` as in this case.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51131/discussion-between-willem-dhaeseleer-and-user193130)

Comment: There appears to be know discussing anything with you, you seem to think you know everything